# .str.lower() returns null values

Tags: python, pandas

In order to convert the strings to lowercase in token_text2['text'], I'm applying .str.lower() as follows:

```
    token_text2['text'] = token_text2['text'].str.lower()
```

But the dataframe returns with null values. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the original input values that produce null values in the result? @PhilipLiu

Comment: You likely don't have string in your cells.

Comment: Would ```token_text2['text'] = str(token_text2['text']).lower()``` work? did you try?

Comment: `str(token_text2['text']).lower()` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps my problem was that I tried to do it after tokenising? I ran the cell before tokenising and now I have what I want

Comment: For the future -- a proper [mre] would show how to *create* a dataframe (even if just a minimal one with only a single item of data in it) for which the output you're demonstrating occurs, so others can reproduce the issue and test proposed fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: I had a dataframe with text that was tokenised. I did str.lower() before tokenising and this has turned all of my text into lowercase successfully.

Thank you everyone for your input.